# Is there any way to recover data from a corrupt 7z multi-volume archive?

Tags: data-recovery, 7-zip, 7za

I have a large 7z archive which was split into ~1000 100mb volumes. One of the volumes (.004) was not completely copied and is only 55/100mb in size.

All other volumes are intact, I've reviewed https://www.7-zip.org/recover.html but I am unable to figure out if there is a way to recover the data.

The contents of the archive is a single .bak file.

I tried to copy part 003 to replace 004 which then 7zip recognized but it fails to export any data past ~400mb of the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are solutions that exist (PAR) and (PAR2) but those files must be created before any corruption exists.  The amount of corruption that is allowed with PAR/PAR2 depends on the amount of PAR2 files created.  However, without a know good copy of the file, you really are out of luck.

Comment: They are not by any chance renamed, where .003 originally was the last one? I.e. do you actually have a last file in the sequence that is smaller than 100MB?